# Can any tel me whether it is possible to call sikuli methods like(find(),click(),wait()) in ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, sikuli

I am able to use sikuli methods in python. But no idea about using in ruby. My professor told me to use ruby instead of python. So, can someone could help me out with this. Small code snippet or steps would be appreciated.
If I want to use below python code in ruby, what all changes I have to make?

```
from sikuli.Sikuli import *
from sikuliwrapper import *

class abc(object):
    def _init_(self):
            self.appCoordinates = (0,0,1024,768)

  def action(self, *args):
           find("abc.png")
           click("select.png")
```

Answer (score 2):

Not going to lie.

http://rubygems.org/gems/sikuli

Its pretty easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do anything using gem sikuli in ruby

1. gem install sikuli
2. you can write function like this

> ```
>   def self.sikuli_move
>     screen = Sikuli::Screen.new
>     screen.click(200, 0)
>   end
> ```

For more details check out this link

1. http://rubygems.org/gems/sikuli/versions/0.2.1
2. http://rubygems.org/gems/sikuli